# Searching an excel and copying values from excel into txt using python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, txt

A while ago a made a program which exported filenames of targets from the raw scan data folder the terrestrial scanner creates. (It's a leica p40 scanner) The idea was go through the folders find unique target names, edit them so they are formatted correctly and save each as a single line in a .txt file.

Now to the actual problem, I recently became more ambitious and now want to expand the code so that it also copies the names to the csv/xlsx file which, contains all the points with coordinates assigned to them, and then uses vlookup or something similar to find the x,y,z coordinates after which the same points with the coordinates would be saved to the initial txt file.

Any and all pointers in the right direction would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

So this is what I have so far and I'm stuck at this point
The control point format is LL.LLNN.L(n/x)
L - letter
N - number
(n/x) - optional "n" or "x"

```
import os
import re

#p is raw scan data path
p = input()

#controlpath is the path where the control txt is saved
controlpath = input()

targets = []

#using walk to find the files inside
for root, directories, contents in os.walk(p, topdown=False):
    for name in contents:
        file = os.path.join(name)
        
        #filtering the contents to get rid of unwanted data
        if file.find("Scan")!= -1 or len(file) < 13 or file.find("Project")!= -1 :
            continue
        elif file not in targets:
            targets.append(file)
        else:
            continue
        
#opening a txt file and formating the data
with open(controlpath+"\control.txt", "w") as cont:
    for target in targets:
        
        target = target[:-9]
   
        if target[3] != "." and target[-1] == "n":
            target = target[:3] + "." + target[3:7] + "." + target[-2:]

        elif target[3] != "." and target[-1] == "x":
            target = target[:3] + "." + target[3:7] + "." + target[-2:]

        elif target[3] != "." and target[-1] != "n":
            target = target[:3] + "." + target[3:7] + "." + target[-1]

        elif target[3] != "." and target[-1] != "x":
            target = target[:3] + "." + target[3:7] + "." + target[-1]
            
#writing the data to the file
        cont.write(target+'\n')
```

Comment: Side note: CSV and Excel are not synonymous.

Comment: I know, the native format of the file containing all the points is csv but if it'll be easier to code I can convert it to xlsx.

Comment: 1) Assuming original `target = ''LL.LLNN.Ln"` then `target = target[:-9]` = `'L'` and I don't see how `target[3]` works? 2) Your `if/elif` can be simplified to `target[-1] in ['n', 'x']` and `target[-1] not in ['n', 'x']` to reduce the lines by half. 3) Use [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module to output file as CSV or [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) to write out as `xlsx` file.